# D3Plus Header Modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, tooltip, d3plus

I am trying to change the hovertext displayed during a mouseover in D3Plus. Specifically, I delete the title associated with a set of data.
Here is a photo to describe what I mean, where the red circle denotes the area of my interest:

[image]

I have found that I can change all of the elements listed inside of the tooltip so far beside the main header as I would call it. I have been searching online on various resources and I have not yet found documentation on this subject. the ".tooltip(["name"])" was a test. My code is as follows

```
<script>
    var sample_data = [
        {"value": 100, "name": "alpha", "growth": 0.9},
        {"value": 70, "name": "beta", "growth": 0.4},
        {"value": 40, "name": "gamma", "growth": -0.3},
        {"value": 15, "name": "delta", "growth": -0.65},
        {"value": 5, "name": "epsilon", "growth": 0.7},
        {"value": 1, "name": "zeta", "growth": 0.2}
    ];
    var visualization = d3plus.viz()
        .container("#viz")
        .data(sample_data)
        .type("tree_map")
        .id("name")
        .value(["name"])
        .tooltip(["name"])
        .size("value")
        .color(function(d){
          return d.growth > 0 ? "#008800" : "#880000";
        })
        .draw();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific key to be used for all labels, which includes both the tooltip titles and the labels on the tree map squares, like this:

```
visualization.text("label")
```

Full documentation of the text method can be found [here](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#text).